# gprbuild/gprinstall doesn't respect encoding

Tags: ada

Building Ada sources for multiple projects, with installing the libraries and sources after each project build, works fine for gnatmake and a gnat.adc containing

```
pragma Wide_Character_Encoding(UTF8);
```

but not for gprbuild, no matter what I try.

```
package Compiler is
    for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-gnatW8");
end Compiler;
```

or

```
package Builder is
    for Global_Configuration_Pragmas use "gnat.adc";
    --The same I used with gnatmake just fine
end Builder;
```

Am I missing something? When I run a program with projects build with gprbuild I get bracket encoding output instead of the Unicode characters.

The build even has -gnatW8 on the command line. In fact, the command line args during each build are identical, but they produce notably different output when a program is run.

*Progress:*
Upon noticing the generated files for stand-alone libraries were not built with -gnatW8, I removed all interface declarations for the gpr files, and build standard shared libraries. Programs built with these respect Unicode, and do not output bracket encoded text. So now, the question is why stand-alone libraries aren't obeying the character encoding pragma or flag.

Comment: Why do you even need to use that pragma? Nowadays you have conversion functions to unicode in standard...

Comment: Is anything specifying `-Wx...` for the binder or is `-z` used somewhere? The section on `-z` in the GNAT UG seems to describe the behavior that you see. Also, how to use these together.

Comment: @darkestkhan, would conversion functions help with handling `type E is (ΕΛΛΑΣ, Éire, USA);` and I/O thereof?

Comment: @B98 No, but while I never thought to check for it before, the automatically generated files (upon looking at them, the stuff used to create stand-alone libraries) are all compiled without -gnatW8. This might be the cause, but it still leaves me without any idea why gprbuild isn't keeping to the encoding declaration.

Comment: Would [GCC bug 80888](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80888) relate to this? (I’m working on patches)

Comment: Yes it most definitely would. Seems to be the actual cause of all of this.